Listing members of a O365 group using Graph
Im using Perl LWP to get some information on groups: owners and members. The strange thing is that listing owners works without any problem, getting the users gives me a return code 200 but with empty content... no users. While I know the group does in fact have members.
The URL I use is like:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<some_id>/members/?$select=id,displayName,userPrincipalName&...

I added the $count and set consistencylevel  to eventual (just in case).
Almost the same URL (owners instead of members) does work.
Running the same URL in Graph explorer does in fact return the members
As far as I can see the permission for members is the same as for owners

Kindof at a loss at the moment. Can you help?
Peter
As requested some code snippets
I'm itterating a list of groups I fetched and create a group object to investigate the group:
            my $group_object = MsGroup->new(
                'app_id'        => $config{'APP_ID'},
                'app_secret'    => $config{'APP_PASS'},
                'tenant_id'     => $config{'TENANT_ID'},
                'login_endpoint'=> $config{'LOGIN_ENDPOINT'},
                'graph_endpoint'=> $config{'GRAPH_ENDPOINT'},
                'select'        => '$select=id,displayName,userPrincipalName',
                'id'            => $group->{'id'},
            );

The object is created whith the group id which I get in the loop. An access token is requested for further calls.
Next I call a method to fetch the members
my $members = $group_object->fetch_members();

fetch_members is a method of the object
sub fetch_members { #   {{{1
    my $self = shift;                           # get a reference to the object itself
    my @members;                                # an array to hold the result
    $self->_set_consistencylevel('eventual');   # setting consistencylevel (did this for debugging)
    # compose an URL
    my $url = $self->_get_graph_endpoint . "/v1.0/groups/".$self->_get_id."/members/?";
    # add a filter if needed (not doing any  filtering though)
    if ($self->_get_filter){
        $url .= $self->_get_filter."&";
    }
    # add a selectif needed, have in fact a select => see object creation
    if ($self->_get_select){
        $url .= $self->_get_select;
    }
    $url .= '&$count=true';     # adding $count just to be sure
    #say "Fetching $url";
    do_fetch($self,$url, \@members); # actual fetch is done in do_fetch()
    print Dumper \@members; # dump the result for debugging
    return  \@members; # return a reference to the resul
    
}#  }}}

do_fetch is a recursive function doing graph requests.
It is created to work with lists of results, like a list of users or groups
sub do_fetch { # {{{1
    my $self = shift;                           # get a reference to the object
    my $url = shift;                            # get the URL from the function call
    my $found = shift;                          # get the array reference which holds the result
    my $result = $self->callAPI($url, 'GET');   # do_getch calls callAPI to do the HTTP request
    # debug problemen met members
    say "\n\n\nZoeken naar: $url";
    print Dumper $result;                       # Dump the complete result
    # end debug
    # Process if rc = 200
    if ($result->is_success){
        my $reply =  decode_json($result->decoded_content);
        while (my ($i, $el) = each @{$$reply{'value'}}) {
            push @{$found}, $el;
        }
        # do a recursive call if @odata.nextlink is there
        if ($$reply{'@odata.nextLink'}){
            do_fetch($self,$$reply{'@odata.nextLink'}, $found);
        }
        #print Dumper $$reply{'value'};
    }else{
        # Error handling
        print Dumper $result;
        die $result->status_line;
    }
} # }}}

The actual HTTP request is done with the callAPI method
sub callAPI { # {{{1
    my $self = shift;                   # Get a refence to the object itself
    my $url = shift;                    # Get the URL from the function call
    my $verb = shift;                   # Get the method form the function call
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(       # Create a LWP useragnent (beyond my scope, its a CPAN module)
        'send_te' => '0',   # not really sure what this does
    );
    # Create the header
    my @header =    [
        'Accept'        => '*/*',
        'Authorization' => "Bearer ".$self->_get_access_token,
        'User-Agent'    => 'curl/7.55.1',
        'Content-Type'  => 'application/json',
        'Consistencylevel' => $self->_get_consistencylevel
        ];
    # Create the request
    my $r  = HTTP::Request->new(
        $verb => $url,
        @header,
    );  
    # Let the useragent make the request
    my $result = $ua->request($r);
    # return a reference to the result
    return $result;
} # }}}

That is all the code there is. Could share the object build/init where the access_token is requested, but that just works.
Hope you can make something of my Perl :D Tried to make it as clear as possible.
BTW: The complete code for the MS Graph module is on my github: https://github.com/peter-kaagman/msgraph-perl
so is the project Im using it in: https://github.com/peter-kaagman/EduTeams which is verry much work in progress. But isnt everything allways :D
A minimal reproduceable sample? Ok...here goes nothing
#! /usr/bin/bash

 token=`curl \
    -d grant_type=client_credentials \
    -d client_id=<some_id> \
    -d client_secret=<some_secret> \
    -d scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default \
    -d resource=https://graph.microsoft.com \
    https://login.microsoftonline.com/<some_tenant>/oauth2/token \
    | jq -j .access_token`

curl -X GET \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<some_group_id>/members \
    | jq .

I can make all sorts of requests with this curl example, but when I ask for the member of a group (of which I know has members) I get an empty result.

Not sure how Perl works, but maybe you need to escape $ in $select. Maybe if you can share more code how do you create the URL and send the request.

No need to escape the $ on other places. Got a list of groups just before the request for members.

Maybe a [mcve] would help.

Ok... turned out I needed more than group.read.all and user.read.all. Added some extra permissions and everything worked like expected.
